Alexa "Can't find skill bundle metadata" internal error
I am trying to develop a skill and after very frustratingly had to find out via trial-and-error that my skill seems to be "broken beyond repair" https://stackoverflow.com/a/79007139/5460596
But even with a brand new project, I immediately get errors that will not disappear no matter what I do. Once I add npm dependencies or code to my project, I only get "There was a problem with the requested skill's response" with the following error-message. I have tried for days to narrow the source down, but it seems rather arbitrary, which worries me the most.
{
        "type": "SessionEndedRequest",
        "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.0c7270aa-f54a-497f-8e97-9a71dec7f1a0",
        "timestamp": "2024-09-24T15:38:34Z",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "reason": "ERROR",
        "error": {
            "type": "INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",
            "message": "Can't find skill bundle metadata for skillId amzn1.ask.skill.XXXXXXXXXXX locale en-US stage development"
        }
    }


I cannot find any resource for this error-message anywhere, and I have no idea how to proceed with this, I cannot deploy or configure anything else myself?
This is the package.json - after I add the custom dependencies to the hello-world-skill something breaks, and keeps "broken", even if I remove all dependencies again. Obviously some bundler/builder is triggered and messes up on Amazon-side?
{
  "name": "alexa-skill-helper",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "description": "alexa utility for quickly building skills",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Amazon Alexa",
  "license": "Apache License",
  "dependencies": {
    "ask-sdk-core": "^2.7.0",
    "ask-sdk-model": "^1.19.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.326.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "googleapis": "^52.1.0",
    "i18next": "^19.4.5",
    "i18next-sprintf-postprocessor": "^0.2.2",
    "ics": "^2.22.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.0",
    "luxon": "^1.24.1"
  }
}


Edit
FYI, here is my model, I just use the default "From Scratch" Hello World intent template. The error occurs filling the intent-slots with auto-delegation - but only AFTER adding the extra nodeJS packages and redeploying
{
    "interactionModel": {
        "languageModel": {
            "invocationName": "meta tester",
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.NavigateHomeIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.FallbackIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "TechSupportAppointmentIntent",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "appointmentDate",
                            "type": "AMAZON.DATE",
                            "samples": [
                                "{appointmentDate}"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "appointmentTime",
                            "type": "AMAZON.TIME"
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "make a tech support slot on {appointmentDate} at {appointmentTime}",
                        "book a tech support slot"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "types": []
        },
        "dialog": {
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "TechSupportAppointmentIntent",
                    "delegationStrategy": "ALWAYS",
                    "confirmationRequired": false,
                    "prompts": {},
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "appointmentDate",
                            "type": "AMAZON.DATE",
                            "confirmationRequired": false,
                            "elicitationRequired": true,
                            "prompts": {
                                "elicitation": "Elicit.Slot.5137408571304957813049571345134513451345.1617658477706"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "appointmentTime",
                            "type": "AMAZON.TIME",
                            "confirmationRequired": false,
                            "elicitationRequired": false,
                            "prompts": {}
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "delegationStrategy": "ALWAYS"
        },
        "prompts": [
            {
                "id": "Elicit.Slot.5137408571304957813049571345134513451345.1617658477706",
                "variations": [
                    {
                        "type": "PlainText",
                        "value": "Ok, what day or date would you like to meet?"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}


I have tried adding your dependencies to a new skill set. there seems to be no problem with the packages. You can check with your code to make sure there are no errors there. You can add few lines of your code to simulate and help with the problem

the issue occurs with AutoDelegation, once the system tries to fill or confirm slots. On a sidenote - the region is set to default US-EAST, but I run the simulator (and the account is linked to) EU, not sure if that is an issue (but still should not be)

Added my model - the issue appears without any code added; in fact the lambda isn't even hit yet at all, because it fails during slot-delegation

This issue is an Amazon-side problem and they are investigating.

Well, I still get the same error on new skills. It has remained unchanged like this for over 2 months, how can such a fundamental issue persist like this?

I can confirm. My issue is when chaining Intents via directives. Nothing wrong with my code neither on the console nor in my dev environment (self-hosting). When I delete the skill and start from scratch all works perfectly for about 10 minutes. Then out of the blue, the Intent delegation stops working throwing me exactly the same error message. Checked locales and languages, device, account and skill region, all seem fine. This must be an issue on Amazon.

To resolve the issue, locate the following JSON block in the Alexa Developer Console’s JSON editor:


"dialog": {
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "TechSupportAppointmentIntent",
                    "delegationStrategy": "ALWAYS",
                    "confirmationRequired": false,
                    "prompts": {},
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "appointmentDate",
                            "type": "AMAZON.DATE",
                            "confirmationRequired": false,
                            "elicitationRequired": true,
                            "prompts": {
                                "elicitation": "Elicit.Slot.5137408571304957813049571345134513451345.1617658477706"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "appointmentTime",
                            "type": "AMAZON.TIME",
                            "confirmationRequired": false,
                            "elicitationRequired": false,
                            "prompts": {}
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "delegationStrategy": "ALWAYS"
        },



If you find this block, try removing it. After doing so, save the changes and test the skill again to see if it resolves the problem. Removing the dialog configuration can sometimes help if automatic delegation or prompts are interfering with intent functionality.

That would be literally the opposite of a solution - my issue is that the delegation does not work in the first place, so not triggering the delegation obviously does not create an error - but that's bringing me nowhere. That's like trying to fix a bug by closing one's eye and pretending it does not exist.
